# Filter for > 10 entries in foreign key object

Tags: python, django

```
organizers = Organizer.objects.filter(events__isnull=False).distinct()

for organizer in organizers:
    print("-----", organizer.name, "-----")
    events = organizer.events.all()
    for event in events:
        if not event.attendees.count() > 10:
            continue

        print(event.first())
```

You can see here I have three queries to return the first event that matches the criteria > 10 attendees. I wonder if there is a better way to combine this logic in one or two querysets instead.

Comment: What if an attendee visits two (or more) events?

Comment: That would be fine. I just need to find the first event (by pk) that has > 10 attendees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2), you can make use of [**`.alias(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#alias) for annotations that you do not need in the `SELECT …` part.

We thus can filter with:

```
Organizer.objects.alias(
    nattendees=Count('events__attendees')
).filter(
    nattendees__gt=10
).first()
```

We here count the same `attendee` multiple times if that `attendee` visits multiple events of that organizer. If we want to count *distinct* `attendees`, you should add `distinct=True` to the `Count` expression.

If you use [django-3.1](/questions/tagged/django-3.1) or older, then you replace `.alias(…)` with [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate).

Since we did not specify an order (and assuming the `Organizer` model has no `ordering` option), it will retrieve *a* `Organizer` for which the condition holds, not *per se* the same `Organizer` each time.

For the `Organizer` with the lowest primary key that satisfies the condition, we thus order with:

```
#                    ↓ annotate if prior to Django-3.2
Organizer.objects.annotate(
    nattendees=Count('events__attendees')
).filter(
    nattendees__gt=10
).earliest('pk')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use filter on annotated value:

```
from django.db.models import Count
organizers = Organizer.objects.annotate(
    attendees_count=Count("events__attendees", distinct=True)
).filter(attendees_count__gt=10).first()
```